# Reverse Engineering a Blisslights BLE Star Projector?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to reverse-engineer this new Blisslights BLE Star Projector by sniffing the outgoing BLE commands through my Android phone, but I've reached a point where I'm just sort of stuck.

I've followed a lot of guides online for reverse-engineering BLE lightbulbs, specifically this one:
http://nilhcem.com/iot/reverse-engineering-simple-bluetooth-devices

I've scanned for the device using the nRF app, found it, and found the service with which the Blisslights app uses to send commands to the device, such as different variations of red, green, and blue nebulae and star patterns. The "Unknown Service" UUID was `00010203-0405-0607-0809-0a0b0c0d1910`, and the specific characteristic used to send commands was the same but ended in `1912`. With that information, I was able to use my Android phone to sniff outgoing commands from my phone using the Blisslights app and look at the log-in WireShark.

All of the `1912` commands I sniffed are below. When I was sniffing them I went through every color command in the app, "Fading, Stars, Nebula, Stars against Nebula, Ocean, Space, Sunrise, etc", so I, unfortunately, do not know which code corresponds to which specific color.

This is where I get stuck. Writing *any* of these values back into the `1912` command in the nRF app does not change the lights, mode, or anything whatsoever on the physical device. When I go to "read" the value that the projector is advertising, it gives me back `00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00` (16 0x00's), assuming because it didn't accept my value I wrote to it.

```
Value: 4fb92c94e652d63a921cd1f2f0ec145173a48dae
Value: 50b92cea18b2a20dd81d9b18e264d9829b3391b2
Value: 51b92cc92d45742ae0005702c2c81d15d1adb8c6
Value: 52b92c3d52ab65ee342aadedd66560ade61ad5fe
Value: 53b92c1394e93c96417af8289aad33d4d4ff3a45
Value: 54b92c2a3670c5083b80ecc06cef462dbad5e366
Value: 55b92cb683a0ff0fdb8997c6ac4c46b507d48104
Value: 56b92c457dbce47d587273fad0a237445e0c87d7
Value: 57b92cff67042133a2d8dba67d0eb89db8002c2c
Value: 58b92c388a3733bb1043a1b1d4c3f7c85de6136c
Value: 59b92c97246e9b04d6f1fdb734e4a8590541b5d5
Value: 5ab92c41e2d43a9fbceb4be5a0cb75657077526c
Value: 5bb92c37810285b4eaef5a08b0fa55484cc2d395
Value: 5cb92c6463ea9ce955738c1ba4375371be4f0d23
Value: 5db92c6a449cee5823f4e9219111f7f49d8fa029
Value: 5eb92c3d2b9eb7c3597ecad401168651039cff1a
Value: 5fb92c3c182fb7804460766ea338594303b26337
Value: 60b92cf692c01088eb5a0d91d031ec6aa099f50c
Value: 61b92ce8f955e466008e026aee4792bb8bfbf92f
Value: 62b92c8aa9db13c11e36165f805fba7b73ae7d16
Value: 63b92cc02fca915366e9f1a26dcc2c3d2377c2b5
Value: 64b92c620d5ed752d8306b43a1e1511d87a81c28
Value: 65b92c1c89460ffe767354935cbcb83f34cbf5ff
Value: 66b92c9a77df378a94b8047b0746c876c4f73e21
Value: 67b92c7657afa236ed33ef4c65c85956f3b05a75
Value: 68b92cfc6e73aab154355d66bf8090cbb6bf97ce
Value: 69b92c1748c66e772c3c0d35194f7438a8e9975a 

Value: f89997825e7831c850139ebadd7d201ac735bac2
Value: f9999789c2a8a2defaa58220412a9f6034b25a98
Value: fa9997daf06f09452e7e2289548f1a3f251b307f
Value: fb9997105bda98bb8d6008a2ba118cb51c971790
Value: fc999781d5d9c5e83b8c083be7eaecfc7571b577
Value: fd9997caa0324e37d993c1e3d5c47be3a9199b08
Value: fe99978217d5ad151004cb67b83f4fe94ff3ab58
Value: ff99979ed0fa3136d404246a5451d6aba07d7acc

Value: 009a97e7878cfa7eae99f366ce0ef26807c49999
Value: 019a97e883534168a293adeb1b0f18ba3275b9d4
Value: 029a9701f7e97406ed66871220ab7ef1eeb3ac50
Value: 039a9735595b262af31d33168c2d6881f823d644
Value: 049a9763d710c775d8a837a27868d9b2435f2d73
Value: 059a97994ec19864c73802bac294a9ee19f18f46
Value: 069a97ebe7f0c36b3a19773661b11ca2978947de
Value: 079a97d80399725f44bae5222e5e0bbdce7ebf83
Value: 089a973b0a55ac895d3b3c9289e2035038abc0b1
Value: 099a97ca7fecfd09fc8c3d1539bfae4808621d6c
Value: 0a9a9728447f7cf632f62d2c24b3c31829cbfddb
Value: 0b9a974373ba9f6f797f9986e569cd7678f99402
Value: 0c9a9756ff894a27a127beb53edac3ba223be125

Value: 6fd9a2898c8ae6f9886e422870147335fc5e58c7
Value: 70d9a2e5da72dcd68bc2d7ab3786a961a7764e01
Value: 71d9a253f71f82c61dbebe39699520a72e11f0c9
Value: 72d9a2b42ad4ddfca030a36763f92b10b38fe893
Value: 73d9a24837806a12bd2f5d8d2583b6cf8f336aa0
Value: 74d9a2aa10abac9b409a8fa39954d49e08205c96
Value: 75d9a2c8dc29c109b1b35032aabbd9408fba69d8
Value: 76d9a2ebfea8e7216fd296927ac4ec6f1e21f68a
Value: 77d9a237e817ecfe9995fcd1c3905bb301430ba9
Value: 78d9a20a3d8d484c36e4198383592847e50875d1
Value: 79d9a28205bfee4ee9fb8608a18f6d548a0dacbf
```

A couple of patterns I noticed are that the first two numbers seem to increment every new command, and the next 4 digits are the same between each command (up to a point where it switches to a new 4 digits). As for the rest of the numbers? No idea. I can't see a pattern anywhere.

Edit: I finally managed to sniff just two of the commands, alternating between Nebula and Stars about 10ish times to see if I could spot a pattern in the results. Unfortunately, I still can't seem to make out any pattern whatsoever. I'm assuming digits 2-6 are session-related because they stayed the same until I closed and reopened the app, then they changed, as you can see below:

```
Value: c7c5207b64ca9fe414e210c249a8da606a863ef5
Value: c8c5204961239e7c67c70045b40acc799edb6625
Value: c9c52013faf771b29ef4a9353f950820b32acd07
Value: cac52026b5d07933491a23bd6b701de747c84f48
Value: cbc5208c56ab84173ac338d4a85e7be6b1f5a46a
Value: ccc520ed45b4a35ed54a7b37586d83805009f975
Value: cdc520f6ea193cb83cd19e5674cd2e0dc4a726e4
Value: cec52068def24e42073b55cbda8670d0fc600eae
Value: cfc5209d4305920e223c6b706816d2791a7d5270
Value: d0c5203ec99c4ef2f921413774bff5bccc905c45
Value: d1c5203d12cc74466fcc5de3ae23b66f3622b390
Value: d2c520dd124ab3885620bfe4d5e4b341eaf8f249
Value: d3c52094d43160b6c61f57f10ec5920f471edba0
Value: d4c52011765f7a7b727c068046d7a2dbc27e2947
Value: d5c520ff5aeb8fa08f78cf22cc4e77729e9dbe77
Value: d6c5205edc055bbb3fbad78c3b12e9a26767c6e1

Value: 87159869260c326c66a8073abb8e75a1d403a21f
Value: 881598b6a79412cc660045fa9f676921e99a5572
Value: 891598419aacaba126ccc59c3f943afb7f6a17e9
Value: 8a1598b9b62f598d0e6869a740c2b74494aa9e37
Value: 8b1598e15e347c2d1ad77cca5609eddaf394cdcb
Value: 8c15981f22dde086ea2bd4c666b6f9d860531c96
Value: 8d1598c1460c1ae3423d84c135df7962c7765965
```

Comment: If you repeat the same commands using the dedicated app, for example switching from red to blue back and forth, do the sniffed commands show any patterns? Maybe just the first characters change, maybe there is something more happening. It's always best to start with a small set of commands until you figure out the patterns

Comment: I did try to sniff 1 single command repeatedly to see if I could get any sort of pattern, but my Android sniffer is no longer producing any logs regardless of what I do in the app now, so unfortunately until I can get logs for 1 command this is all I have.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post with more commands. Since there is no real pattern except for the first digits this could also be a manufacturer defined encryption to force you to use their app

Comment: Interestingly enough, I did actually manage to control the star projector one single time without using their official app. I noticed in my sniffed log that the app was writing a *request*, `01`, to the `1911` characteristic before actually writing a *command*, `87159869260c326c66a8073abb8e75a1d403a21f`, to the `1912` characteristic. So I did that in the app and the 87159etc number changed it to stars only, and the 88159etc number changed it to nebula only. Unfortunately, after hours and hours of retrying that exact same thing, I cannot reproduce it for the life of me.

Comment: Maybe you need to get your hands on a BLE sniffer, like [this one](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Sniffer-for-Bluetooth-LE) from nordic. You would need one of the development boards, a dongle like the [nRF52840 Dongle](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/nRF52840-Dongle) is the cheapest option. The tool works with wireshark and I am using it very successfully for debugging purposes